# No matter what code I give, only chrome opens with only google.com

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser

I am facing issues with launching websites from `firefox` and `chrome`. I have referred online blogs and chatrooms on the same but could not find any helpful support, hence I would require someone to assist me on this.

I have run the following code multiple times using different URLs, but all the time, chrome opens with `google.com`. At the same time, I have used the firefox driver as well but inspite of that chrome opens with `google.com`.

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ADITYA\\SELENIUM TEST LAB\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get ("google.com");

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\ADITYA\\SELENIUM TEST LAB\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get ("google.com");
```

Please help/suggest on what change needs to be done.

Comment: Did you try to change the address you try to open? `driver.get ("google.com");` <- this line

Comment: I did everything....I tried with different URLs but all the time, only chrome and only google.com is opening